# Cannot Test Facebook Open Graph Action

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to test out an Open Graph Facebook action and am having trouble wrapping my head around how to do it. I used this video to get started: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8x6T7-WFSBg . It gives me an error when I try to run the code (which I've pasted below). I figured I'd just test out and see if I'm getting the correct response by going to http://graph.facebook.com/me/APP_NAME (with app_name of course being replaced with my apps namespace). I get this error though:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

I'm assuming the reason I can't test my action is because there is no active access token? The problem I'm finding though is that I'm the administrator on the app so I'm assuming I should have that access either way.

Here's the code used (from that video) in order to just have an easy basic test for an Open Graph action. Be aware that I have substituted the app's info wherever the words are all caps. Thanks for your help in advance, I'm very new to the Open Graph and am just trying to dive in. Thank for your patience with me as well!

Here's the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
     <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# APP_NAMESPACE: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/APP_NAMESPACE#">
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="APP_NAMESPACE:ACTION" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="Put your own URL to the object here" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample ACTION" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <input type="button" value="test" onclick="javascript:postAction('ACTION', 'OBJECT', 'URL OF THIS PAGE');" />

     <script type="text/javascript">
    function postAction( action, object_type, object_url ){
        FB.api('/me/APP_NAMESPACE:' + action + '?' + object_type + '=' + object_url, 'post', function(response){
            if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert('Error occured');
            } else {
                alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'APP_ID', // App ID
          status     : true, // check login status
          cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });

      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
       }(document));
    </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: try supplying the access token also.

Comment: Where do I find my access token?

Comment: you will that as the response of FB.login. see the docs

Comment: Oh ok, I was assuming since I was an administrator I didn't need an access token?

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate your user with the app
check here for more info: http://hayageek.com/facebook-dialog-oauth/ or via facebook dev http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/